# How to update container code without running docker-compose build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

When I make changes to any code in my development, the change does not reflect until I run `docker-compose up --build` again

The `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

... and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
server:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rake db:create && rake db:migrate &&  bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"

    links:
      - db
      - redis

    volumes:

         - ./myapp
```

This set up worked well on my OS, not sure why it's not working the same on Windows. 
The structure for folder stored locally `C:/users/docker/projects/myapp`.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Looks like you've commented out the `volumes` mapping for `./myapp` in your `docker-compose.yml` - the `COPY` in the `Dockerfile` is a point in time copy done when the image is built, the `volumes` mapping is basically mounting your local checkout into your container at the expected path during the runtime (removing the `volumes` mapping and you'll be running the version of the checkout that was copied into the image when the image was built).

Comment: @masseyb, I had it commented in the question, I fixed the question. That does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3385
This worked for me.

Right-click the dir
Click properties
click the security tab
click the "Edit" button.
click the add button
Type "users" in the text box
click "Check Names" (should auto fill/update for you)
click okay
Highlight your newly added group.
10 . Under "Permissions for [User/Groupname]" select Full control
click apply
Click "OK"
Click "OK"